# DataGrid или аналогичный контрол с динамическим набором столбцов

Tags: wpf, xaml

Нужно решение хоть для `DataGrid` хоть для `ListView (View == GridView)`

Есть класс. Примерно такой

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<MyClass2> List1 { get; set; }
    public List<MyClass2> List2 { get; set; }
}
```

Нужно вывести его на форму таким образом, чтобы `List1` отображался в первом столбце по подготовленному мною шаблону для `коллекции<MyClass2>`, а каждый элемент `List2` - в отдельном столбце по подготовленному мною шаблону для `MyClass2`. Естественно, для `коллекции<MyClass>` каждый элемент имеет одинаковое количество элементов в `List2`

Проблема в том, что

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding ...} ItemTemplateSelector={SomeSelector}>

</DataGid>
```

Не работает. Конкретно не работает мой `DataTemplateSelector`. Программа даже к нему не обращается (указал его в разметке верно, он создается).

В случае с `ListView` код немного другой, но общий смысл в том же.

Когда я пытаюсь в коде создавать столбцы, я не знаю как мне обратиться из шаблона к нужному полю в ViewModel. Все потому, что `DataGridTemplateColumn` не имеет биндинга, поэтому в шаблоне я имею всю строку. Если бы не динамически создаваемые столбцы, я бы для каждого столбца создал отдельный темплейт, который бы биндился к нужному полю, но я же в такой ситуации все поляне знаю. Сколько их там будет? List2[0], List2[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLLEE.png).... и так до бесконечности.

**UPD:**

Вот так должен выглядеть результат при наборе данных

```
new List<MyClass>
{
    new MyClass
    {
        List1 = new List<MyClass2>
        {
            new MyClass2(),
            new MyClass2(),
            new MyClass2(),
        },
        List2 = new List<MyClass2>
        {
            new MyClass2(),
            new MyClass2(),
            new MyClass2(),
            //и тд.
        },
    },
}
```

[image: пример результата]

Как видите, List1 выводится в столбец как набор контейнеров, сформированных из элементов типа MyClass2, а List2 поэлементно разбивается на столбцы, в которых по одному элементу.

**UPD2:**

Пока нашел вариант, который будет работать, здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20493184/datagridtemplatecolumns-autogeneratecolumns-true-and-binding-to-a-datatable (в ответе, который помечен как ответ), но он уродлив в плане поддержки

Comment: Пока плохо понятно, можете изобразить примерно как должно выглядеть и примеры данных List1, List2, MyClass2?

Comment: Навскидку напрашивается привязка к чему-то такому: `public IEnumerable List => new object[] { List1 }.Concat(List2);`

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns="True"

Comment: @Андрей добавил пример результата

Comment: @iRumba, т.е. у вас всегда будет одна строка?

Comment: @Андрей, нет, строк может быть сколько угодно

Comment: @iRumba, ага, понял. Ну для начала попробуйте это: `var list = new List<MyClass>(); ...; list.Select(myClass => new object[] { myClass.List1 }.Concat(myClass.List2));` если это подойдет - останется только транспонировать таблицу

Comment: @Андрей, ну почему же не подойдет. Подойдет. Я еще пробовал так же создавать DataTable, создавая заранее все столбцы. А в итоге споткнулся на том, что все сгенерированыые автоматически столбцы DataGrid имеют тип DataGridTextColumn и не используют никаких темплейтов и темплейт селекторов. Просто игнорируют их.

Comment: @Андрей, а если создавать столбцы в коде динамически (DataGridTemplateColumn), а темплейты в xaml (что логично), то темплейты эти в хамл получают всю строку целиком. То есть я не могу указать ему источник данных. Вот и остается только генерить хамл разметку в коде через xaml parser, чтобы подсунуть в DataContext элемента в темплейте нужное поле (((

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за правку, конечно, но DataGrid это конкретный контрол, а мне не особо важно, какой контрол будет использован для решения (из бесплатных, конечно). Будь то ListView или wpftools:DataGridControl или еще что. поэтому я просто обобщил )

Comment: @Андрей, я нашел решение, если интересно. Но публиковать пока нет времени )

Comment: @iRumba: Простите, я думал, что опечатка. Дело в том, что `Grid` — это тоже конкретный контрол. Поменял снова, посмотрите, правильно ли так?

Comment: @VladD, ну да, поэтому я написал Грид а не Grid ). Да, теперь намного лучше, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем решил так

Создал собственный тип столбца

```
public class DataGridProcessContainerColumn : DataGridBoundColumn
{
    public DataTemplate ContentTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        var control = new ContentControl();
        control.ContentTemplate = ContentTemplate;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(control, ContentControl.ContentProperty, Binding);
        return control;
    }
}
```

Далее в обработчике события, где генерируется столбец делаю так

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    DataTemplate template = null;

    if (e.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEnumerable<MyClass2>)))
        template = (DataTemplate)Resources["MyClass2CollectionTemplate"];
    else if (e.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MyClass2)))
        template = (DataTemplate)Resources["MyClass2Template"];

    if (template != null)
    {
        var col = new DataGridProcessContainerColumn();
        col.Binding = (e.Column as DataGridBoundColumn).Binding;
        col.ContentTemplate = template;
        col.Header = e.Column.Header;
        e.Column = col;
    }
}
```

В ресурсах окна у меня лежат соответствующие темплейты

Можно, конечно, было сделать вообще красиво через `DataTemplateSelector`, но не было времени. Если кому надо, то допилить несложно.

Ну и, конечно же, саму модель я превращаю в `DataTable`. код преобразования я приводить не буду, это уже специфическая задача. Там просто создаются столбцы с нужными названиями и типами (тип данных сохраняю какой есть, то есть `typeof(MyClass2)`)